# How to stop your plugin from executing on certain pages?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm building a plugin that extends WooCommerce and I want to prevent it from executing once it hits the `template_redirect` hook. My goal is to stop the plugin from loading all the assets on non-product pages. Any ideas on how to do this?

### Code

```php
add_action('template_redirect', array($this, 'stoplight'));

function stoplight() {
        $post_type = get_post_type();
        if ($post_type != 'product') {
            return;
            //I used wp_die() here as well, but it killed WordPress.
        }
    }
```

Comment: The proper way to control when assets pod is to use the appropriate conditions in the enqueue hooks. Not to completely terminate the plugin. What are you actually trying to stop running?